# Split String and insert it in different input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, split

can you please help me how to split a string in an input and insert those split strings into different inputs? I already tried some codes that I found here but it still didn't work.

I actually want to store the string in that 2 different inputs (those not hidden) after exectuting the functions

This is the source code:

```js
function split() {
  var strings = $("#qrstring").attr("value").split("<br>");
  if (strings.length == 2) {
    qrData(strings, 1);
  }
}

function qrData(value, index) {
  if (value.length == 2) {
    $(".idnum").attr("value", value[0]);
    $(".idname").attr("value", value[1]);
  } else {
    alert("malformed strings");
  }
}

let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
  video: document.getElementById('preview'),
  mirror: false
});
scanner.addListener('scan', function(c) {
  window.document.getElementById('qrstring').value = c;
});
Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function(cameras) {
  if (cameras.length > 0) {
    scanner.start(cameras[0]);
  } else {
    console.error('No cameras found.');
    alert('No cameras found.');
  }
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.error(e);
  alert(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="qrstring" value="" split(); qrData();>
<label id="label">Account ID </label>
<input type="text" name="accId" required="" class="idnum" style="width: 108px;margin-right: 15px;" value="">
<br/>
<label id="label">Customer Name </label>
<br/>
<input type="text" readonly="" name="name" class="idname" required="" value="">
```

Comment: This appears to be JavaScript code, not PHP. I've re-tagged it for you. If you don't use the correct tags, your question will not be seen by people who have the correct skills to help you!

Comment: `value="" split(); qrData();` looks like wishful thinking.

Comment: When do you want to split? Will the hidden field already have values? If so, why not fill the fields on the server?

Comment: @ADyson oh sorry hehe

Comment: @mplungjan that is hidden because I want to store the string data that was scanned since I assumed that the string can only be split if the string is in the input field. hehe Let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: So the missing information is that QRData is actually some data scanned from a QR code reader. When is that happeneing and what is the event that is triggered when scanning?

Comment: If in case you want to know the process, I have this qr scanner. Every QR that will be scanned has an ID Number and a name. So after scanning, I want to split the ID Number and the name and put it into different inputs.

Comment: Please add that to the question. And answer me what is the event  - on input?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

https://plungjan.name/SO/QR/

```js
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
  video: document.getElementById('preview'),
  mirror: false
});

Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function(cameras) {
  if (cameras.length > 0) {
    scanner.start(cameras[0]);
  } else {
    console.error('No cameras found.');
    alert('No cameras found.');
  }
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.error(e);
  alert(e);
});


$(function() {
  const re = /(\d+-\d+)\s+(.*)/;
  scanner.addListener('scan', function(content) {
    console.log(content);
    if (!re.test(content)) {
      console.log("malformed strings")
      return;
    }
    const [_, id, name] = content.match(re);
    $(".idnum").val(id);
    $(".idname").val(name.trim());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
<label id="label">Account ID </label>
<input type="text" name="accId" required="" class="idnum" style="width: 108px;margin-right: 15px;" value="">
<br/>
<label id="label">Customer Name </label>
<br/>
<input type="text" readonly="" name="name" class="idname" required="" value="">
```

Works on this QR

One line

[image]

Two lines

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: Let me  know if I need to change the account ID and  name by the way